# solution verification - determine $a, b, x$ so that $\overline{ab}^2 = \overline{xxb} $ and $\overline {ba} ^ 2 = \overline {bxx}$

Tags: solution-verification, square-numbers

**question**

Determine the non-zero digits $a, b, x$ so that $\overline{ab}^2 = \overline{xxb} $ and $\overline {ba} ^ 2 = \overline {bxx}$.

*my idea*

We can see that $10 \leq \overline{ab} \leq 31$ for $\overline{ab}^2$ to be a 3-digit number.

Also $\overline{ab}^2 = \overline{xxb} $ means that $b \in {1,5,6}$ because the last digit of the second member is b and the first member is $\overline{ab}^2$ and these are the only last digit that squared have the same digit.

From here we have only 7 possible cases: $11,15,16,21,25,26,31$

First of all, I want to ask you if my rationament is correct. Also, is there any way to shorten these cases?

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Do $a$, $b$ and $x$ represent digits?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, you are right!

Comment: You should specify that in the question.

Comment: What about $a=b=x=0$?

Comment: @jjagmath Because they are first digits i suppose they cant be 0

Comment: What does the bar at the top of $\overline{bxx}$ mean?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash What do you mean? I don't understand!

Comment: @ТymaGaidash The bar appears to mean the $3$-digit number with digits $b$ followed by $x$ followed by $x$, etc.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Your approach is correct; to further shorten the list of cases, you can use the constraint $\overline{ba}^2 = \overline{bxx}$. The square of a $2$-digit number starting with $5$ or $6$ can't be a $3$-digit number starting with $5$ or $6$, so you can eliminate all cases with $b \in \{5,6\}$, leaving only $11$, $21$, and $31$ to check.